# Wheels sliding vs rotating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Lets say we have a straight ramp with a given angle of inclination. We have a wheel that just rotates and doesn't slide, and another one that just slides friction-less. If both wheels are identical in mass, form and volume, and both start under the same conditions...

- Which one will make it to the ground first?

First wheel:
[image]

The second wheel is the same, but without the friction (couldn't find image)

---

- What if the second wheel has dynamic friction now? (with a given coefficient)

Comment: Which one speeds up the most (which one gets higher speed)? Think of energy conservation. We only have a certain amount of energy, given by the start height as potential energy - what is the energy used for in each case?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts going into this about what the solution might be?

Comment: @Steeven Yes neither lost or created. Mr. Robot, is this a HW problem or test question? - if so please label it as such

Comment: Think about the total energy that either wheel has at the bottom: kinetic energy from rotation and translation must equal the potential energy lost. If you don't rotate, all that energy is turned into ... now can you see which will be faster?

Comment: @docscience none, just pure curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where the wheel rotates, you have two forces which affect the acceleration of the wheel along the incline.

1. $mgsin(\theta)$ acting dowards
2. $f$ frictional force acting upwards (this causes the rotating)

In the case where the wheel slides without rotating, you have only one force which affects the acceleration of the wheel along the incline.

1. $mgsin(\theta)$ acting dowards

In the first case, the net force which is responsible for accelerating the body is lesser than the net force in the second case. It does not matter whether or not the wheel is rotating, the force causes an acceleration of the center of mass. Therefore, the wheel will reach the ground first in the second case.

> What if the second wheel has dynamic friction now? (with a given
>   coefficient)

The first case had dynamic friction. Dynamic friction is not the correct word. It is static friction. The frictional force starts from zero and increases to the maximum as the velocity of the center of mass increases.

If a wheel must not slide, it must satisfy the following condition:
$$v_{center-of-mass} = \omega R$$

The velocity at the lowermost point of the wheel must be zero if it has to slide. This is possible if and only if the above condition is satisfied. The frictional force adjusts itself such that the condition is maintained (well, friction loves to prevent the motion of the lowermost point, i.e: the point of contact between the two surfaces).

At some point, the frictional force will reach to its maximum. Now the frictional force won't sufficient to prevent the wheel from sliding and hence, the wheel starts to slide from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 2nd wheel will reach first because ..in case 1[ when the wheel reaches ground the potential energy is stored as both rotational kinetic  energy (which is half of moment of inertia ×angular velocity squared ) and as linear kinetic energy ( u know 1/2 m×v squared)..].. But in case 2[the potential is stored completely as  linear kinetic energy]. You can show this mathematically too..
If there's a dynamic friction there will be no case 2 only case 1 and which will reach faster depend on the coefficient of friction